# How can I install the release version of Ubuntu 21.10 after I have installed the beta of 21.10

Tags: reinstall

I installed a beta of 21.10 over 21.04. Now that 21.10 is released I want to install the released version over the Beta version.It keeps telling me I have the latest version but there are some things that aren't right.

Comment: As long as you install all the regular updates there should be absolutely no difference. What things aren't right?

Comment: Edit your question and include details. Be exact. Without any details we don't know what steps you are taking, what errors or notifications you are receiving, or what problems you are experiencing. Tell us exactly what you're doing to reproduce the problem. Give us all errors and messages complete and verbatim and tell us exactly what you mean that things "aren't right".  We aren't with you to study your device so we have to rely on only the information you provide.  Make sure it's clear

Comment: My *impish* development system through normal upgrades became a *stable* 21.10 system about two days before actual release.  This is one of the last changes made as the *daily* images became RC or *release candidate* status. Nothing special is required; you may need to `sudo apt full-upgrade` is all. If you `lsb_release -a` or `neofetch` (if installed for your system) does it still say *development* ?

Answer (score 3):

My *impish* development system through normal upgrades became a *stable* 21.10 system about two days before actual release.

This (*name change*) is one of the last changes made as the *daily* images became RC or *release candidate* status.

Nothing special is required; though you may need to `sudo apt full-upgrade` is all.

If you

`lsb_release -a`

or `neofetch` (*if installed for your system as it is for some flavors like what I use*) does it still say *development* ?

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/uwn$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

I did nothing more than my normal `full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Update` > `Updates` In notify me of a new Ubuntu version select the option `For any new version` save the settings then close.

Now go to `Software updater` it will check for the new update. Install it.